# Which pattern to store the selected item of a list in Redux

Tags: redux, react-redux

Let's imagine I want to be able to select a task in the [Todo](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/todos) with React-Redux.
Where should I store this state ?

First solution: Add a `isActive: true` attribut to the task

Second solution: Create a new reducer just to handle the id of the selected item.

I dislike both solutions: the first one feels like I'm storing something unrelated to the task in it, the second one feels overkilled to create a whole reducer only to store an id.

Is there any other option ? What's best ?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say it depends on your use case.

1. For a big app that has tons of UI state to persist, it makes a lot of sense to have a special reducer to mutate a slice of the store related to the UI.
2. It is valid to have a `isActive: boolean` property per task if you can have multiple tasks active at the same time. Even though it's not related to the task from the task data perspective, it actually is from an application perspective of the task. Your redux store main goal is to be your application source of truth rather than just mirroring your API data models.
3. You can also have a single `isActive: id` if you can only have a single task active/selected at the time.
4. You can also just use the component state. The limitation of this is that it won't persist and it won't be shared. For instance, if you want to have a save button, that button will have to be within the component that has the selected state.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing really wrong with either of the two options you've listed. But, if you're looking for other options, you can

1) Include the selected item in the todos reducer state, so your state object would look like this:

```
{
  selected: id,
  list: [{id, text, completed}, ...]
}
```

2) If you don't need the selected item anywhere else in your app, you can simply store it in your local state. There's nothing wrong with mixing both Redux for application state and local state for data contained solely within your component.

Comment: Thanks. If I use the first solution, once I want to modify the id, how do you ensure the new state is immutable (and doesn't refer the same list array)
The only solution I found is

var newState =JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state))
newState.selected = action.id

Comment: I found more information about that here: https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html

Comment: If you use the first solution, you just have to change the value of selected with the id of the new selected item. There’s no need to change the array of the list. You mutate the array only if there a change in the list because you add, remove or update an item. In this case, where there’s only one selected item at the time, changing the selected item does not change anything on an item data itself.